# How to create a Nginx's root to a specific Symfony's route?

Tags: symfony, nginx, symfony4, nginx-location

I'm trying to personalise a specific route when user using a specific url. Actually, I have two domain names for one website. First for french and second one for dutch. So when user using first url, I would like show /public as usual. But if user using second url, I would like show public/index.php/nl. But it's a Symfony's (4+) route. I have create two config files for Nginx. But dutch config show me /public and not /public/index.php/nl. How can I do that with Nginx. I hope it's understable.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my-nl-site.be my-nl-site.be;
    root /var/www/html/mysite/public;
    index index.php/nl  

    location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
            try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: what do you assume is `index.php/nl`? (also, every non-block directive in nginx has to end on `;`) You do understand, that the `index` directive actually has to designate a **file**, right? and since index.php cannot both be a file (for the french version) and be the directory in which nl is supposedly located (for the dutch version) you have to find a different approach. I'm sure there is some tutorials on how to organize multi-locale sites (probably even with nginx examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution with Symfony. I created a controller in addition.

```
class AppController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="root")
     */
    public function root(Request $request)
    {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $myhost = $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST');

        if( $myhost == 'mywebsitenl.be'){
            $locale = 'nl';
        }else{
            $locale = 'fr';
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home', ['_locale' => $locale]);
    }
}
```